# Exploring a t-distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, normal-distribution

I am tasked with creating a t-distribution for a homework problem. I have created the code, but I get a result that doesn't look like a t-distribution. What am I doing wrong?

**Task:**

[image: task]

```
u=0
n=20
for i=1:5000;
    r=randn(20,1);
    x(i)=mean(r);
    s(i)=std(r);
    t(i)=(x-u)/(s/sqrt(n)) ;
end
hist(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I suspect that you are not using the operator that you think you are using. [division is not just limited to scalars](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html), and here you're accidentally getting a scalar result from a matrix operation.

Hint: when you calculate the ith value of t, you probably only want to be using the ith terms for mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Matt, you have forgotten to iterate through the means and standard deviation values. What are you doing now is dividing two arrays. Matlab interprets your code then as scalar product of array x and transposed array s. That is why the result is a scalar and the error is not so easy to spot.

Updated code should be fine:

```matlab
clc
clear

u=0.0
n=20

for i=1:5000
    r=randn(n,1);
    x(i)=mean(r);
    s(i)=std(r);
    t(i)=(x(i)-u)/(s(i)/sqrt(n)) ;
end
hist(t)
```

Generated result for me:

[image: t distribution]

Hint: For small scripts I advise you to add clc (clear command window) and clear (clears workspace) command lines. Sometimes there might be a lot of garbage from previous runned scripts that might spoil the result, and clearing command window definitely make it easier to debug, at least for me.

Comment: hmm its not letting me select this as the answer